# can't install zombiejs on windows 8.1

Tags: node.js, npm, zombie.js

I've been trying to install zombie.js via `npm install -g zombie` but keep getting this error: `LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file 'libcpmt.lib'` I've been searching for a solution to this for the past 3hrs, but haven't had any luck. I read that it may be a pathing issue and to use `vcvars32.bat` but that didn't work.

the reason I want to use zombie.js is because I need to create folders locally for each link I find in the DOM. I would use casperjs, but I don't know of a way to communicate back and forth between nodejs and casperjs

(gather current folder names then pass it to casper, gather all links via casper, compare folder names to link names, then pass the names that are different to node so it can create new folders based on those names)

Comment: Why are you installing it with the global switch `-g`?

Comment: admittedly I'm pretty new to npm, but I wanted the ability to access it globally (like i can casper and phantom) is that not something that should be done for zombie (the error above happens regardless of using -g or not )?

Comment: If you just need to scrape html, you might look at something more lightweight, like [`cheerio`](https://github.com/cheeriojs/cheerio).

Comment: You access casper and phantom via command line, so it's appropriate for them to be installed globally, but zombie is used as a module in a node.js code (`var Browser = require("zombie");`) so it should be installed in your app only.

Comment: @laggingreflex ahhh, ok gotcha.

Comment: There seem to be similar issues http://google.com/search?q="npm"+LINK+:+fatal+error+LNK1104:+cannot+open+file+'libcpmt.lib' might be fruitful looking into, particularly this one https://github.com/brianc/node-postgres/issues/165#issuecomment-7484945

Answer (score 0):

The missing library can not be fixed , However what worked for me is installing Visual Studio Community Edition grab it **[here](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9863608)** , now all build processes should work as expected.